# Flutter: How to jump to last page dynamically created on a PageView

Tags: flutter

I have a pageView displaying a list of pages.

Application provides a + button to add a new page at the end of the collection.

I need the pageView to automatically jump to the last page once this new page has been successfully created.

If I try to redisplay the view providing a provider with initialPosition set to last pageView index, it does not work

```
PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: false);
```

Any implementation idea ?

- Using listener (but which listener ?)

Complete code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_userId == null) {
      return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Loading experiences")));
    }
    print('Rebuilding entire view.');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: StreamBuilder<ExperiencesInfo>(
              stream: _experiencesInfoStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  _selectedExperience = snapshot.data.currentExperience;
                  return Text(snapshot.data.currentExperience.name);
                } else {
                  return Center();
                }
              }),
          ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 16.0,
        ),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child:
                StreamBuilder<List<Experience>>(
                    stream: _userExperiencesStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return  _createExperiencesPagesWidget(snapshot.data);
                      } else {
                        return Center();
                      }
                    })
            ),
            _buildPageIndicator(),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            _displayAddMenu();
          }),
    );
  }



_createExperiencesPagesWidget(List<Experience> experiences) {
    print('Creating ExperiencesPagesWidget ${experiences}');
    return PageView.builder(
      physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: experiences.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              _buildMoodIndicator(experiences[index]),
              _buildMoodSelector(),
            ]));
      },
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        if (_actionType == ActionType.none) {
          print('page changed to index: ${index}, updating stream.');
          _experiencesViewModel.experienceIndexSink.add(index);
        } else {
          _actionType = ActionType.none;
        }

      },
    );
```

Page controller is defined as a class property

```
PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: false);
```

Answer (score 43):

`PageController` contains methods that you can use to dynamically switch between pages.

```
// Create the page controller in your widget
PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: false);


// Use it in your page view
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  PageView(controller: _controller, ...);
  ...
}


void onAddButtonTapped() {
  // add the new page
  ...

  // use this to animate to the page
  _controller.animateToPage(lastIdx);

  // or this to jump to it without animating
  _controller.jumpToPage(lastIdx);
}
```

Comment: Tx for the answer. My pb is that I do not use a "manual action" (onAddButtonTapped) BUT I need to automatically jump to the page once the new page has been added (StreamBuilder is call when new page is added and pageView is rebuild)

Comment: Can you call the `animateToPage` function in the stream listener?

Comment: How do you attach a listener to the StreamBuilder to be informed build layout has been done ?

Comment: Can you post your code with the StreamBuilder? It's hard to understand what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Code available. Tx

Comment: You left out the code for `_displayAddMenu` which is also relevant. Based on what you've included, it seems like you should be able to add the logic to go to the last page in that function.

Comment: _controller.animateToPage(1,duration : Duration(milliseconds: 300),curve:Curves.easeIn); , we need to give duration and curve as well along with pageNumber

Answer (score 0):

I think the question here is how to move programmatically from one page to another page which was added after the widget has been created. In the very beginning, there is only one page. When a user enters information correctly on this page, next button became active and another page is added. User can click next and it should jump or animate to the next page. But this approach does not work if I try to really add pages into an array of widgets shown in PageView. It just does not show the next page even if in fact there are pages. I think the problem here is linked to the fact that controller initializes something when attached to a view. And it does not reinit it even if setState is called.

So my workaround for this situation is to add all the required pages in init. Even if there will be placeholder widgets instead of the required pages. Then I have to programmatically control if swipe action is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Since **PageView** doesn't have something built up to manage its indexPage outside widget i can add this btw I an using *riverpod*,

```
//A value that will keep listening to changes (You could change this reference in any other widget)      
final int actualIndex = ref.watch(indexPageSelectedProvider);

//Then call
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if(actualIndex != pageController.page!.toInt()) {
        pageController.jumpToPage(actualIndex);
      }
});
```